# Feature Points on Mesh

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, vertices, vertex-colors

I didn't start using Blender yet since I would like to know whether it's is the correct place to do my work on.

The case is as follows:

I have a mesh (XYZ- coordinates, faces) represented as Graph(the XYZ-coordinate here is the same, having edges now), and I'm trying to do the following (not sure if the process is in this hierarchical), 
extract descriptors and obtain feature points(coloring them), in order to work on them as featured connected components.

I code in python, I tried to obtain Zernike moments and Fourier transform as descriptors the output is vectors, but I can't visualize these vectors on the mesh? or I wasn't able to do so, as well I need to obtain the feature points.

Is this the right place to work with?
[image]

I obtain these result for teapot object

```
The graph matrix is  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 ... 0 0 0]]
The zernike moments are:    [0.31830989 0.13789404 0.18738977 0.21210616 0.09979722 0.25386089
 0.16402911 0.29690689 0.26002601 0.12894862 0.07586501 0.48601007
 0.45855364 0.20280874 0.0126834  0.54532024 0.46835978 0.34243193
 0.13314587 0.09234412 0.03764165 0.159134   0.45475221 0.1222509
 0.17898168]
the fourier transorm is:  [[602.983833    +0.j          68.2650495 +308.71994353j
   68.2650495 -308.71994353j]
 [-76.48185048 +58.97442939j -41.7166658  +68.44586843j
  -65.40655281 +99.04981891j]
 [-70.793392   +31.66322377j -78.84787903  +0.77550291j
  -44.83406506  +0.51857595j]
 ...
 [-44.23448408 +10.60125082j -26.79330393 +12.57477038j
  -37.14294225 +40.98371836j]
 [-70.793392   -31.66322377j -44.83406506  -0.51857595j
  -78.84787903  -0.77550291j]
 [-76.48185048 -58.97442939j -65.40655281 -99.04981891j
  -41.7166658  -68.44586843j]]
```

And I would like to visualize these features on the object but what somebody told me is that I need to get the feature points and these points in which I should colorize them on the object?

Comment: The last code part in this answer allows to give vertex groups values in order to see the result https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146819/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-mean-curvature-of-a-triangular-mesh/147371#147371 Alternatively, you can also add vertex colors

Comment: The answer is you can do anything in blender, but you need to at least try. [ask].

Comment: The question is clear, but maybe you should indicate which kind of visualization you want for these vectors (as vectors placed at the corresponding points? As colors? others?)

Comment: @Merlin what is the problem with my question!

Comment: @lemon , the vectors I obtained is zernike moments for example, but what I did is that I make the input (the whole shape) while I'm reading know that I have to detect interest points(feature points) then for each I make descriptor extraction for all obtained interest point.Visualization is about visualizing the feature points on the shape [Zernike Visualize](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Shape-Classification-Using-Zernike-Moments-Vorobyov/711be25acba94fbf913d2b734d312c27d5fe5226/figure/0)

Comment: @RoaaSolh search and research is the first item.  Beyond this you should edit your question to include the image you have posted as a comment.

Comment: @lemon as well please if you have knowledge about this: despite the colorization ok, What I'm trying to do is to extract feature points from the descriptors(multi-scale descriptors) like Zernike moments 3d shape context etc.. do you know how the process follows? Thanks for your assist really

Comment: @Merlin Post is edited but without the image, since I'm not sure like this must be the visualization. Thanks but I really I'm trying hard in searching

Comment: Have you looked at [using blender as a vizualization tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/is-there-a-tool-for-scientific-visualization-using-blender)?

Comment: @RoaaSolh, have few (very few) knowledge about this, but is it to compare several meshes? (PS: except for feature points, is it ok for the colorization from the previous answer?)

Comment: @lemon yes I'm tending to get featured connected components and make matching between them, I mean match two featured connected components that refers for sure for objects.

Comment: Also please, I used to work with conda environment and PyCharm editor to install packages and write python code, could you guide me please where should I start, since, for example, I used pymesh to be able to read mesh and graph-tool to represent it as a graph. Sorry, my question may be silly, but I'm trying to learn how could I combine my work with different things.

Comment: I think you want GNU Octave (OS version of MATLAB) instead of blender.  It has a mesh function that does exactly what you want.  If not then please edit your question to include all the comments here.  The more work you put into the question the more people will read it and contribute an answer.

Comment: @Merlin Sir, may you assist me with good documentation for what I can do, I downloaded previously Octave but badly I wasn't able to find that since you know I don't have much knowledge with it. Thanks for your assist.